# Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 18.04

I want to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on my Hewlett-Packard Pavilion laptop. Is there an uncomplicated way of doing this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi works for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Ignore reference to Wubi.

Comment: Hi user276634 and welcome to askubuntu! It works fine and you can already find many answers to your questions on askubuntu. Ubuntu / Linux provides everything you need, and to make life uncomplicated I suggest to make the whole disk an ubuntu one, and use windows on a virtualbox. You can also dump your windowsdisk as vhd  and let it pay in virtualbox!

Answer (score 0):

If you have pre-installed Windows on your system, then it is very straightforward just take:

1. Make bootable Ubuntu 18.04 in any bootable medium like DVD or USB.
2. Select USB/DVD on startup from boot menu.
3. Take standard steps and select install Ubuntu along with Windows installation.
4. Select disk space allocation by dragging the slider to assign sufficient disk space (minimum 20GB)
5. After this proceed with setup by selecting timezone, computer name and username with password.